# Completeness of 2-category of Monoidal Categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, limits-and-colimits

Is the 2-category of monoidal categories complete? If not, can any conditions be imposed to satisfy completeness?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "the 2-category of monoidal categories" and also what you mean by "complete".

- The 2-category of monoidal categories and strict monoidal functors is complete as a Cat-enriched category in the sense of enriched category theory, hence also complete as a bicategory.
- The 2-category of monoidal categories and strong monoidal functors is not complete as a Cat-enriched category, but it has all [PIE-limits](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/PIE-limit) and hence all pseudo-limits, and therefore is complete as a bicategory (has all "bilimits", i.e. bicategorical limits).
- The 2-category of monoidal categories and lax (resp. colax) monoidal functors is not even complete as a bicategory, but it does have an [interesting class of limits](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2111), including all colax (resp. lax) limits.

Comment: Thanks, what about cocompleteness (for the first bullet)? Does MonCat (with strict monoidal functors) have small colimits?

Comment: Yes, because it is the category of algebras for an accessible 2-monad on a locally presentable 2-category (namely Cat).  The second bullet is also cocomplete as a bicategory; Blackwell-Kelly-Power proved this using the pseudo-morphism-classifiers and flexibility.  I don't know whether the third bullet has any colimits.

Comment: Isn't the category of algebras usually taken as the strict algebras? I guess the possibility of replacing a pseudo algebra with a strict algebra helps here, or am I mistaken in the first place?

Comment: @KevinCarlson Yes, the category of algebras is the strict algebras.  There is in fact a 2-monad whose *strict* algebras are *non-strict* monoidal categories; this is how one generally operates in 2-monad theory.